# Delphi 7 - WebService error in Service Application but not in Form Application

Tags: multithreading, web-services, delphi, soap

I am having a strange problem while calling SOAP methods in Delphi Service Application. Here's the situation.

Service Application has a thread that is executing same query on a database. Now while not query Eof I am trying to execute some SOAP method with parameters from current record and I am getting an error message that follows: A connection with the server could not be established - URL: (blah blah blah) - SOAPAction: (blah, blah, blah).

Now you will say - Perhaps your service was unable to establish connection to the server? But wait, I have created a separate project (form application this time, not a service), I have used the same thread unit and did the same that service does that is I created thread and resumed it, nothing else, all logic is in the thread. And what? Everything is ok, I am executing SOAP methods with no error.

Perhaps this is a lame question but why is that the same thread is working fine in form application and is erroring in service application?

It is all in Delphi 7 and tested on Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacenter with Data Execution Prevention enabled but both Service.exe and ThatOtherProject.exe are added as exceptions.

Has anyone encountered similar problem?

Comment: Which Service account do you use to runn your Service Application. Windows Vista and newer including Windows Server 2008 now have different service acounts. Each of these service accounts has different system acces. Some have network support while others don't. You can find more information here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd367859(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: I cannot believe it was that easy !!! Thanks

Comment: Wait so I was actually right? I was basically just guesing that this might be the cause but definitly wasn't sure since I have no expirience with actual development of service applications so far.

Comment: I have no experience of service applications neither :P your guess was right. I would mark you as a correct solution if it wasn't just a comment. thanks again